# How to change the 1st value of a list to a float

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, list

```
def read_data(filename):
    answer = []
    in_file = open(filename)
    lines = in_file.readlines()
    lines = [line.strip() for line in lines]
    for line in lines:
        answer.append(line.split(","))
    return answer

 ANSWER --> [['Angus McGurkinshaw', '25'], ['Thomas Albert Finkelstein III', '75'], ['Myrtle', '50']]
```

I can't figure out how to change the number of every object in the list to a float can anyone point me in the right direction.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code to

```
for line in lines:
    name,val = line.split(",")
    answer.append([name,float(val)])
```

if you know for sure you get 2 elements back and the 2nd is float-convertable.

---

If you want to modify your result list: you can create a `tryFloat(string)` method that takes a `string`, returns it as `float` if it float-able, else return the string back:

```
def tryFloat(t:str):
    """Tries to convert t to float and returns it, returns t if not a float."""
    try:
        f = float(t)
        return f
    except (ValueError,EOFError):
        return t

data =  [['Angus McGurkinshaw', '25'], ['Thomas Albert Finkelstein III', '75'], ['Myrtle', '50']]

data2 = [ [tryFloat(f) for f in y] for y in data]

print(data2)
```

And apply that to your list of lists. If you know for sure the 2nd thing is a float, use one of the other suggested methods though. The tryFloat() would work for floats at arbritary locations as long as you only have lists of lists of string.

Output:

```
[['Angus McGurkinshaw', 25.0], ['Thomas Albert Finkelstein III', 75.0], ['Myrtle', 50.0]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
row = line.split(",")
row[1] = float(row[1])
answer.append(row)
```

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over your `answer` list. For each entry, invoke the `float()` constructor.

```
for line in answer:
    line[1] = float(line[1])
```